# Nested Dynamic PHP Class

Tags: php, class, object

I may just need a terminology update, but I have been playing in Magento and Joomla, and they do references like

```
$mage = new Mage;
$mage->block('blockname');
```

where class Mage through some process I am failing to figure out is calling:

```
class blockname extends something{

}
```

Don't quote me on that code, however I am looking to do something like that where I have a file that I can do $myscript->block('blockname'); and it will load and call the file with class blockname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Mage {
    private $block;

    public function block($blockname) {
        if (!class_exists($blockname, true)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Not a valid class name: $blockname");
        }
        $this->block = new $blockname;
    }
}
```

The loading of the class definition (if not already done) is typically accomplished through autoloading (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)).

Comment: Ah, I did not know you could do "new  $varible".  Thanks!